# DNN Linear Regression. MAE measurement error

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network

I am trying to implement MAE as a performance measurement for my DNN regression model. I am using DNN to predict the number of comments a facebook post will get. As I understand, if it is a classification problem, then we use accuracy. If it is regression problem, then we use either RMSE or MAE. My code is the following:

```
with tf.name_scope("eval"):
    correct = tf.metrics.mean_absolute_error(labels = y, predictions = logits)
    mae = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, tf.int64))
    mae_summary = tf.summary.scalar('mae', accuracy)
```

For some reason, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-396-313ddf858626> in <module>()
      1 with tf.name_scope("eval"):
----> 2     correct = tf.metrics.mean_absolute_error(labels = y, predictions = logits)
      3     mae = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, tf.int64))
      4     mae_summary = tf.summary.scalar('mae', accuracy)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/metrics_impl.py in mean_absolute_error(labels, predictions, weights, metrics_collections, updates_collections, name)
    736   predictions, labels, weights = _remove_squeezable_dimensions(
    737       predictions=predictions, labels=labels, weights=weights)
--> 738   absolute_errors = math_ops.abs(predictions - labels)
    739   return mean(absolute_errors, weights, metrics_collections,
    740               updates_collections, name or 'mean_absolute_error')

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py in binary_op_wrapper(x, y)
    883       if not isinstance(y, sparse_tensor.SparseTensor):
    884         try:
--> 885           y = ops.convert_to_tensor(y, dtype=x.dtype.base_dtype, name="y")
    886         except TypeError:
    887           # If the RHS is not a tensor, it might be a tensor aware object

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, preferred_dtype)
    834       name=name,
    835       preferred_dtype=preferred_dtype,
--> 836       as_ref=False)
    837 
    838 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in internal_convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref, preferred_dtype, ctx)
    924 
    925     if ret is None:
--> 926       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
    927 
    928     if ret is NotImplemented:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in _TensorTensorConversionFunction(t, dtype, name, as_ref)
    772     raise ValueError(
    773         "Tensor conversion requested dtype %s for Tensor with dtype %s: %r" %
--> 774         (dtype.name, t.dtype.name, str(t)))
    775   return t
    776 

ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype float32 for Tensor with dtype int64: 'Tensor("eval_9/remove_squeezable_dimensions/cond_1/Merge:0", dtype=int64)'
```

Comment: So, I changed:

y = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=(None), name="y") to y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None), name="y") and the problem was gone. BUT, is this the right solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line in your code:

```
correct = tf.metrics.mean_absolute_error(labels = y, predictions = logits)
```

executes in a way where TensorFlow is first subtracting predictions from labels as seen in the backrace:

```
absolute_errors = math_ops.abs(predictions - labels)
```

In order to do the subtraction, the two tensors need to be the same datatype. Presumably your predictions (logits) are float32 and from the error message your labels are int64. You either have to do an explicit conversion with `tf.to_float` or an implicit one you suggest in your comment: defining the placeholder as float32 to start with, and trusting TensorFlow to do the conversion when the feed dictionary is processed.